# Use matching groups as arguments in function

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where we have the size of people in american notation and i want to replace these values in centimeter with a regex (or other ...)

```
#approximation
def conversion(one, two):
    print(one)
    return (int(one)*30 + float(int(two)*2.5))

df_test = df_dummies
df_test['Height'] = df_test['Height'].replace({r'(\w+)\+(\w+)' : conversion( r'\1' , r'\2' )}, regex=True).astype(float)
```

I've tried this but the matching groups doesnt work

error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-189-d4278403d30f> in <module>
      5 
      6 df_test = df_dummies
----> 7 df_test['Height'] = df_test['Height'].replace({r'(\w+)\+(\w+)' : conversion( r'\1' , r'\2' )}, regex=True).astype(float)
      8 df_test.head().transpose()

<ipython-input-189-d4278403d30f> in conversion(one, two)
      2 def conversion(one, two):
      3     print(one)
----> 4     return (int(one)*30 + float(int(two)*2.5))
      5 
      6 df_test = df_dummies

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\\1'
```

but if i do this :

```
#approximation
def conversion(one, two):
    print(one)
    return (int(one)*30 + float(int(two)*2.5))

df_test = df_dummies
df_test['Height'] = df_test['Height'].replace({r'(\w+)\+(\w+)' : r'\1' +r'\2' }, regex=True).astype(float)
```

It work fine and i got the concatenation of the 2 matching groups

Is there a solution to get the result a conversion(one,two) as replacement in the dataframe ?

Comment: Could you provide some example data and expected output?

Comment: Your strings probably contain `'` and `"` characters  that cause the conversion error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Series.str.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) which supports the callback as the replacement.

```
def conversion(m): 
    return str(int(m.group(1))*30 + float(int(m.group(2))*2.5))

df_test['Height'] = df_test['Height'].str.replace(r'(\d+)\+(\d+)', conversion).astype(float)
```

The callback function take one argument which is the regex match object. you will need to  return a String as the replacement.

Comment: Waw ! absolutely brillant, thanks for help, as you've guess i'm beginner in python and i dont really understand mechanisms of callback...Thanks you for your help !